# Как задавать несколько типов данных в ООП

Tags: python, ооп

только начинаю изучать ООП питона.
Код:

```
class Nikola:
    __slots__ = ['name', 'age']
    def __init__(self, age=0, name='Николай'):
        self.name = name
        if self.name != 'Николай':
            self.name = f'Я не {self.name}, а Николай'
        self.age = age

name1 = Nikola(age=13, name='Миша')
name2 = Nikola(age=32, name='Николай')
name3 = Nikola()
print(name1.name)
print(name2.name)
print(name3.name)
```

Возник вопрос. Как сделать, что, если при вызове класса Nikola параметр age был не указан,  то при print(name3.age) выводилось "Возраст не указан", если параметр age был передан, то
при print(name3.age) должен выводить возраст.

Comment: `print(name3.age or 'Возраст не указан')`

Comment: @andreymal, Мне нужно, чтобы при вызове метода Student.set_name_age я мог не передавать параметр age. Если он не передан, то при вызове Student().get_age() выводить 'Возраст не указан', если передан, то выводить age

Comment: В показанном вами коде не существует метода get_age. Но даже в этом случае вам ничего не мешает записать `self.age or 'Возраст не указан'` внутри нужного вам метода

Comment: @andreymal, извините, совсем другой класс написал вам. Переделал, спасибо, помогло

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Python язык с динамическим типом данныx, в следствии чего вы можете в конструктор класса в качестве стандартного значения передавать строку:

```
def __init__(self, age='Возраст не указан', name='Николай'):
```

Comment: Что грозит ошибками, если, например, добавить функцию увеличения возраста.